# How to show a terrain on Google Maps v2 without showing the default markers?

Tags: android, maps, label, hide

I have an Android application that uses Android Maps v2. I use a JSON file to show a map that has no labels.

```
MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mapWithoutLabels);
map.setMapStyle(style);
```

However, I can also set the mapstyle to show terrain:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
```

The problem is that this second command overwrites the first one. I can't seem to combine these two. When I set it to GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, then it shows labels that I don't want on my map (e.g. from nearby companies), but when I use the JSON file, I can't specify that I want the mapType to be 'terrain'.

Is there some way to show the terrain but hide all labels?

Thanks!